# Log file on Git (Heroku)

Tags: git, logging, heroku, ignore

Hi if my question is asked before i am sorry but i cant find exact problem. and i am new at github so i coudn't find my answer.
my problem is i have a facebook app on heroku (php). when users enter my main page some informations written in ..log/log.php . but when i make changes and push my website log file become empty. i know its normal. even i do not anything heroku updates my log file and make it empty. i want my log file to never change and keep its data. i tried .gitignore , git update-index --assume-unchanged, git/info/exclude but none of them worked. what can i do?
thanks and sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

You should log to stderr instead: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing-to-your-log